# I just want to remove the word "class"

Tags: php, html

I have this code, when I clicked it, look at the picture i want the 137 value only that will display but the word "class" was displayed also
[image]

```
<a  rel="facebox" href="portal.php?id='.$rowa["_id"].' class="icon-remove"></a><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i>
```

here is the portal.php code

```
<?php

 $id=$_GET['id'];

 ?>
 <form>
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $id ?>" name="id">
 <label>Are you sure you want to remove this charity on your list?</label></form>
```

Comment: Missing a `"`. `href="portal.php?id='.$rowa["_id"].'"`..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've a HTML typo

```
<a  rel="facebox" href="portal.php?id='.$rowa["_id"].'" class="icon-remove">
                                                     ^^^
```

instead of

```
<a  rel="facebox" href="portal.php?id='.$rowa["_id"].' class="icon-remove">
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Check the difference your `href` attribute is not closing perfectly over here

Comment: Thank you buddy , Its ok now!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the html a tag attributes you forgot to close the `"` in you a tag attributes

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
<a rel="facebox" href="portal.php?id='<?php echo $rowa["id"]?>'" class="icon-remove"></a><i class="remove glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign glyphicon-white"></i>
```